# Magento admin panel not accessible - secured site issue

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404

for magento when i go to www.mydomain.com/admin, it will redirect to https://www.mydomain.com/home/index.php/admin/. error 404. I think this is unsecured url issue. how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

just try with below solution to change value in `core_config_data` data

find this `web/secure/base_url` and change with simple **http or https**

or if you have multiple store or view you can change according to that.

Also please don't forget to clear your cache.

hope this will sure help you.